# How to return a class which contains a nested class in wcf?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a class as MethodResponse. Here it is:

```
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract]
    public class MethodResponse
    {
        public enum ResponseType
        {
            Succeed,
            Error,
            NotValid,
            DataIsAlreadySaved
        };

        [DataMember]
        public ResponseType Type;

        [DataMember]
        public string ResultText;

        [DataMember]
        public object Object;


    }
```

I try to return MethodResponse from WCF. I can return it if I won't set the Object field but when I set value of Objet, it returns an error like this.

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:49601/CustomerService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
```

Here is my wcf and db class function

```
           public MethodResponse GetCustomerById(int _id)
            {
                CustomerDb db = new CustomerDb();

                return db.GetCustomerById(_id);
            }

           public MethodResponse GetCustomerById(int _id)
            {
                try
                {
                    MethodResponse mrMethodResponse = new MethodResponse();

                    using (var contex = new TestEntities())
                    {

                        contex.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                        Customer customer = contex.Customers.FirstOrDefault(cstm => cstm.id == _id);
                                 mrMethodResponse.Type = MethodResponse.ResponseType.Succeed;
                        mrMethodResponse.Type = MethodResponse.ResponseType.Succeed;
                       mrMethodResponse.Object = customer;


                        return mrMethodResponse;
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to return `object`. It's not allowed. You should specify concrete class or generic type.

Change property type from

```
    [DataMember]
    public object Object;
```

To

```
    [DataMember]
    public Customer Object;
```

You also must ensure that `Customer` class is serializable.

Comment: Yes, but I use MethodResponse to return any type of objects. And also MethodResponse is in another ClassLibrary as a helper lib. So that lib doesn't know my db objects.

Comment: You cannot return `any type`. Service Client should know excactly what types if objects you can return. You may serialize your object into string like JSON and return `string` property.